# Slow response with Camera shutter by AVfoundation framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, camera, avfoundation

recently I am working on a camera app and everything is doing good but one thing: The shutter response is unbelievable slow....That cause of very poor her experience. Here is my code for capturing:

```
- (void)captureThe7Head {
AVCaptureConnection *myVideoConnection = nil;
for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in myStillImageOutput.connections) {
    for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {
        if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {

            myVideoConnection = connection;
            break;
        }
    }
}

[myStillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:myVideoConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
        if (imageDataSampleBuffer) {
            NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
            UIView* exportView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1500, 1500)];
            if (!isBackCam) {
                UIImage* img = [self squareImageFromImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData] scaledToSize:1500.0];
                img = [self flippingBack:img];
                [exportView addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img]];
            }
            else{
                [exportView addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self squareImageFromImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData] scaledToSize:1500.0]]];
            }
            UIImageView* overlayFrameView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1500, 1500)];
            overlayFrameView.image = [frameDict objectForKey:selectedFrame];
            [exportView addSubview:overlayFrameView];
            [self passingImgToShareWith:[self captureImageFromView:exportView] AndSelectedFrame:[frameNameArray indexOfObject:selectedFrame]];
        }
    }];

}
```

Can anyone help one the solve this issue??? I really find no example on the web for this....Please help.

Attached with the screen recording of the response:  http://youtu.be/_yH8za8loE8

When the shutter is triggered, it will call the method above.

Comment: Is it the shutter response that's slow (i.e. the period between pressing the button and the image being capture), or is the delay in processing and displaying the captured image that's the issue? It's unclear from your video...

Comment: @Wildaker I think is the delay in processing..

Comment: Then it's not really the shutter response that's slow—you need to work though your image processing to find the bottleneck. After all, you appear to to be altering some pretty big UIImages—it won't be instant!

Comment: @Wildaker so is there are any comment practise I can try to smoothy the process???

Comment: Firstly, are you capturing full-sized images? Do you need full-sized images? If not, use one of the video presets. Do you really need to resize the images? Also try to avoid using `UIImage`s except for display—keep to `CGImageRef`s for processing. The best thing you can to is log how long each part of the process takes (`NSLog` the time), so you can identify the bottlenecks and then work to optimise those areas.

Comment: @Wildaker Thanks! I don't need a full size image unless user is passed to next screen for saving and sharing. Can I tell me how can I use CGImageRef to serve similar preference I need to preform?? And how can I NSlog the process time???

Thanks!!!

Comment: I don't wish to be rude, but these are pretty basic questions—you should search on the Internet for how to crop using Core Graphics and how to use `NSLog`, and just generally work on your core iOS development skills before digging too deep into `AVFoundation`; it's non-trivial stuff.